# Is it possible to loop in SQL data blocks?

Tags: sql, databricks

```
select a.Client, a.Period_Id, a.Business_Name, a.Tax, a.Number_Workers,
       a.Business_Item, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date, a.Taxpayer
from sii_2014_1 as a
      inner join (
                  select Client, count(Client) as uniques
                  from sii_2014_1
                  group by Client
                  having count(Client) = 1
                 ) as b
      on a.Client= b.Client
```

Which removes the original Client if you have duplicates along with their duplicates. I did this for the sii_2014_1 table. But I want to do it for 2 other tables that are called sii_2015_1 and sii_2016_1. The only thing that changes from the tables is the last digit of the year so I thought I could use a loop to save code. Is this possible in the SQL of the DataBricks?

Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only three and instance to take care and I beleive that the intend is to reduce the code  , I suggest you to explore creating a view which you can use in your query . 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-view.html